# How do I remove SASS from a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have forked a rails project and found that is uses SASS, I want to remove SASS and write my css by hand.

Can i just delete the folder:public/stylesheets/sass? Remove the gem from the gemfiles, and then continue with the .css files that sass has generated?

Comment: Just curious: why would you like to remove SASS and use CSS ?

Comment: Because i am just learning rails, and the css that sass is generating is giving me errors in the Aptana IDE, I would rather write it by hand and remove the learning curve for SASS and just focus on rails.

Comment: When removing the sass gem, you'll need to stop using it for CSS compression by changing `config.assets.css_compressor` in config/environments/production.rb from `:sass` to `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is already generated SASS, the method you suggest is the best. You do not want the SASS files overwriting your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The files with .css extension have no treated by gem sass, you can write your .css file think to change stylesheet_link_tag in layout for load your .css